# How to store object data in redis in nodejs rest service

Tags: node.js, rest, redis

I am trying to make rest web service in `nodejs` and using `redis` for caching purpose to improve performance. I want to save as a object like offer which has id, offer name and vendor.

I do not want to have different key to have for all these. What is the way to do in a single key.

```
app.get('/insertOffers', function(req, res) {
    const {id, offerName, offerVendor} = req.query;
    client.set('offers', ) // client is my redis client
});
```

Comment: If you really want it to be *all* in a single key, consider using [hashes](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-hashes), and do [`HGET`/`HSET`](https://redis.io/commands#hash)) instead of `GET`/`SET`. However, there is a drawback that hash items can't have independent expire times. And normally there's *really* no harm in having a lot of keys in Redis, so using something like ``client.set(`offers:{id}`, JSON.stringify({name: offerName, vendor: offerVendor}))`` should be the way to go.

Comment: @drdaeman I have saved as you suggested `client.set('offer:{id}', JSON.stringify({name:offerName, vendor:offerVendor}));` it worked but when I am trying to get offer id wise then it does not work. Whatever id I pass it always return same last saved result. not id wise. can you please suggest how should I implement in such a way when I pass `client.get('offer:{id}', function(err, reply) {
            console.log(reply);
        })` then it should offer id wise. I think it is overriding last data in offers not saving id wise also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @drdaeman says in the comment, using a Redis Hash offers you the ability to query a single key, where the sub-keys or hash keys is a unique key. The command would look something like the following:

```
HSET offerId offerJSONString
HGET offerId offerJSONString
```

So in your express function, you could do something like:

```
app.get('/insertOffers', function(req, res) {
    let offer = {
      id: req.query.id, 
      offerName: req.query.offerName,
      offerVendor: req.query.offerVendor
    }

    client.hset('offers', offer.id, JSON.stringify(offer), yourCallbackFunction);
});
```

Note, you when you get the data, you will need to JSON.parse it.

```
client.hget('offers', offerId, function(err, offer){
  let offer = JSON.parse(offer);
  // do something with offer
})
```

I think the preference for a single key can be valid, like if you want to later delete all the offers with a single command, without a lookup. Redis is really fast though, so there shouldn't be a heavy performance cost to 2 round trips to the redis server.

Comment: Can't we do like `client.set('offer:{id}', JSON.stringify({name:offerName, vendor:offerVendor}));` and `client.get('offer:{id}', function(err, reply) { console.log(reply); })`

Comment: @Williams Yes of course, this would be the normal approach. However in your original question, you state "I do not want to have different key to have for all these." A hash gives you 1 key per to store all the offers. Effectively they are the same, since you need the 'offer' prefix and a key.

Comment: I have this `let offer = {
        id: req.query.id,
        offerName: req.query.offerName,
        offerVendor: req.query.offerVendor
    }
    client.hset('offer', offer.id, JSON.stringify(offer));` and getting this node_redis: Deprecated: The HSET command contains a "undefined" argument.
This is converted to a "undefined" string now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.
Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you intended it to.

Comment: you can add `redis.print` as the 4th argument, like on the hset example [github page](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#usage-example)